# Multiple button functionality

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am just wondering if it is possible to have a button in a buttonfield within a gridview to complete several things with the same click.  Specifically, I'm trying to have the button enable edit mode, change a column of the gridview from a 0 to a 1 (basically just checking a box in numeric form rather than clicking the actual button) and then apply the changes like an update function button would do.

Comment: In your app would you ever want to exit out of edit mode before editing? If not, I would have the event handler do all three actions on the first click. Otherwise I would strongly consider refactoring your architecture to be MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fake it by having multiple button on top of each other and only showing one at a time.

Or have a single button with a variable stating the state of the button.

```
Enum ButtonStateEnum
    EnableEdit
    ChangeColumn
    DoSave
End Enum

Private _state As ButtonStateEnum = ButtonStateEnum.EnableEdit

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Select Case _state
        Case ButtonStateEnum.EnableEdit
            ' ...
            _state = ButtonStateEnum.ChangeColumn
        Case ButtonStateEnum.ChangeColumn
            ' ...
            _state = ButtonStateEnum.DoSave
        Case ButtonStateEnum.DoSave
            ' ...
            _state = ButtonStateEnum.EnableEdit
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can have the event handler for a button do whatever you wish - it can be one action, or a series of actions.

In your case, you would just perform those three actions in your code handling the Button's click event.

Comment: Perfect answer. Exactly what I was thinking. +1